# Tracking the end of the gif display Python 3.x, Kivy

Tags: python-3.x, image, kivy, gif

Hellow. I have an app showing gifs. At certain moments (the binding goes to the actions of the mouse and keyboard), the basic gif is changed to a number of others. Each gif has a different duration.

```
class Animation(Image):
    def setAnim(self, string, anim_loop = 1):
        self.source = string
        self.anim_delay = 0.1
        self.anim_loop = anim_loop
```

This class is responsible for replacing the characteristics of the current gif.

I googled similar questions. People use the Animation class and there is an on_complete event in it. Unfortunately, according to the documentation, there is no analog of this event in the Image class.
This is about how I would like to see the finished result. (((This code does not work, for the reasons described above)

```
class Animation(Image):
    def setAnim(self, string, anim_loop = 1):
        self.source = string
        self.anim_delay = 0.1
        self.anim_loop = anim_loop
        Image.bind(on_complete = self.on_complete)

    def on_complete(self, *args):
        self.source = default_gif
        self.anim_loop = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hack that has worked for me (no guarantees):

```
class MyImage(Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.num_frames = None
        super(MyImage, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_texture(self, instance, texture):
        super(MyImage, self).on_texture(instance, texture)
        print('on texture', self._coreimage.anim_index, self.num_frames)
        if not self.num_frames:
            self.num_frames = len(self._coreimage._image.textures)
        else:
            if self._coreimage.anim_index == self.num_frames - 1:
                print('anim done')
```

Note that defining a custom class with the same name as a standard kivy class can cause confusion. I would suggest avoiding  making a custom class with the name `Animation`.

Comment: I don't understand how to track the triggering of the `on_texture` event. Here is an example for App class: `Window.bind(on_drop_file = self.funcName) ` - this event triggering when I upload file to window of app. What does such a record look like for `Image` ?

Comment: You don't need to do a `bind` when you are dealing with properties of an `EventDispatcher`. Simply defining a method with the name `on_<property_name>` in the class is enough. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/events.html#dispatching-a-property-event).